# VM Crashed - syslog - Invalid ssh key entry

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to work out why my VM crashed at about 09.02 today Last entry in syslog is :

```
Sep 12 09:01:36 debian google_guest_agent[461]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:199 Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: ecdsa-s---n---- XYZA>
Sep 12 09:01:36 debian google_guest_agent[461]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:199 Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: ssh-rsa XYZF>
Sep 12 09:01:36 debian google_guest_agent[461]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:199 Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: s----:ecdsa-sha2-n---- XYZAz>
Sep 12 09:01:36 debian google_guest_agent[461]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:199 Invalid ssh key entry - expired key: s----:ssh-rsa XYZA>
Sep 12 09:01:36 debian google_guest_agent[461]: Updating keys for user s----.
```

Could this be connected to my VM crashing ?

Comment: the key is expired. but this question looks like a end-user question. did you consider and contacted the Google support?

Comment: wordpress runnning on GCP VM (E2 small), last entries in syslog before crash are above.  And I wasnt using SSH at that time.

Comment: and that is your private blog?

Comment: woocommerce website

Comment: let's start over, give enough information, what you want, what you tried, and what research did you already... and running woo commerce does not make it to a business related question

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to discover why my site crashed, I'm still setting up mariadb error logging so I cant check those.  The last entries in syslog are above. They seem odd as I was not using ssh and they are seconds before the site went down.

Comment: well check as a professional business administrator would do, read logs, for Webserver using apache or nginx and for MySQL and mariadb as usual in /var/log. if its a product issue, contact the Google support

Comment: Great thanks, I'm new to GCP so am working where the logs are and how to check them all.